# Representing a mathematical operator in a class

Tags: java, operators, anonymous-types

I am trying to have an efficient way of doing this code.

```
try {
    switch (op) {
        case "+":
            BinaryOperation addition = (double n1, double n2) -> n1 + n2;
            result = calculator.perform(addition, calculator.pop(), calculator.pop());
            calculator.push(result);
            break;
        case "-":
            BinaryOperation minus = (double n1, double n2) -> n2 - n1;
            result = calculator.perform(minus, calculator.pop(), calculator.pop());
            calculator.push(result);
            break;
```

I am trying to create an object that takes in any two numbers and (add them or multiply... Whatever the operator is.)

```
public static final BinaryOperation OP = (double n1, double n2) -> 
        (double) new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(n1 + T + n2);
```

How can I get T to represent any operator (+ , -, /..). It doesn't matter if it's through ScriptEngine or not.

In other words, how can I get the + to be represented by a variable that holds any type of operator

```
public static final BinaryOperation OP = (double n1, double n2) -> n1 + n2;
```

Professor's instruction: [image]

If you care to check the full instructions this is the [link](http://cs.smu.ca/~myoung/csci2341/)

Comment: You would have to make it a parameter too.

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question, but perhaps you are looking for the `BiFunction` generic interface.  All these operators are `BiFunction<Double,Double,Double>`.  There's also a subinterface `BinaryOperator` that seems to fit.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am looking for a generic type that is able to represent mathematical operations. I'm not allowed to use outside classes.

Comment: These interfaces are part of the JDK.  They're not outside classes.  You could even use them in some kind of map, such as `HashMap<Character, BinaryOperator<Double>>` to look them up by the character that represents the operator.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem you see I'm not allowed to do any of that. There are many ways to do this but the professor wants it done in a way that I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: Well, I've told you how to do it.  If there are additional requirements, you'll need to express these more clearly.  I am incapable of reading your professor's mind, so if you're not clear about what he/she wants, it might be best if you talk to him/her directly.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I have attached the instructions. For some reason my comments keep being removed I dont understand why

Comment: @Elias Moderators (Yvette Colomb in particular) removed some comments that seemed no longer necessary. Thanks for clarifying your question. I've updated my answer. Does this satisfy the constraints from the instructions?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do something like this?

```
try {
  BinaryOperation operation = (double n1, double n2) ->
    (double) new criptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(n1 + op + n2);
  result = calculator.perform(operation, calculator.pop(), calculator.pop());
  calculator.push(result);
}
```

(I assume that you got the part with the script engine right).

---

**EDIT**

Here is a version without script engines, which simply stores all available binary operations in a hash map. This might be seen as a somewhat more concise alternative to the `switch`-`case`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.DoubleBinaryOperator;

class A02 {

  public static final HashMap<String, DoubleBinaryOperator> 
    SupportedBinaryOperations = 
    new HashMap<String, DoubleBinaryOperator>(){{
      put("+", (x, y) -> x + y);
      put("-", (x, y) -> x - y);
      put("*", (x, y) -> x * y);
      /* etc */
    }};

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     String op = "+";
     double a = 40.0;
     double b = 2.0;
     double result = Double.NaN;

     // excerpt from the stack-processing method that replaces switch-case
     result = SupportedBinaryOperations.get(op).applyAsDouble(a, b);
     // ...handle exception if no operator found etc.

     System.out.println("Result: " + result);
  }
}
```

The definitions of each binary operator are reasonably concise, I'd say, definitely shorter than the `switch`-`case`. I don't see what constraints from the exercise text it violates.

PS: I probably should note that in Java it's more common to indent by 4 spaces.

Comment: That does really do anything. I am trying to have the variable op contain "+" or "-" or "/"... I am looking for a generic type that is able to represent mathematical operations

Comment: @Elias Why not simply check with an `if` whether the operator is one of `+-*/`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the RPCalculator how to perform each of the operations, according to your professor's instructions. You have to give a separate BinaryOperation implementation for each. But they can't be in separate source files.

Lambda's are a great way to do that, as you've already discovered. And a `Map` is a great way to remember to link between the operator symbol and the BinaryOperation implementation.

To tie these things together, you'd be looking at something like this:

```
public class RPCalculator {
    private Map<String, BinaryOperation> operations = new HashMap<>();

    public void addOperation(String operatorSymbol, BinaryOperation operation) {
        operations.put(operatorSymbol, operation);
    }

    public void perform(String operatorSymbol) {
        BinaryOperation operation = operations.get(operatorSymbol);
        // omitted: Validate input parameters. What to do if operation isn't found? 
        double result = operation.perform(pop(), pop());
        push(result);
    }

    public void push(double value) {
        // ...
    }

    public double pop() {
        // ..
    }
}
```

```
public class A02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RPCalculator calculator = new RPCalculator();
        calculator.addOperation("+", (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2);
        calculator.addOperation("-", (n1, n2) -> n1 - n2);
        // etc

        calculator.push(1);
        calculator.push(2);
        calculator.perform("+");
        System.out.println(calculator.pop());
    }
}
```